# Ambiguous argument origin/master when using --git-dir and --work-tree options

Tags: git

I'm using git to manage my workstation's dotfiles, using a setup described [here](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=11070797) for storing the repository itself. It basically solves the problem of version-controlling the homedir by placing the repository folder itself into a side folder (I use `~/.dot`) and creating an alias to git that specifically points to the repo and work tree individially. My alias is `alias dot="/usr/bin/git --git-dir=$HOME/.dot --work-tree=$HOME"`. I can successfully version control my entire homedir (I have `config status.showUntrackedFiles no` for sanity) and use commands like `dot status`, `dot add ...`, and `dot commit ...` to manage my ever-changing configurations.

The problem I'm running into is that I want to be able to write a script that (forcefully) updates my local configurations from my remote repository. I've seen many places that suggest using git reset, in a manner like:

`dot fetch origin
dot reset --hard origin/master`

This approach makes total sense, and in fact I have seen first-hand somebody using this approach in their scripts, but when I use it I get the following error:

`fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin/master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'`

Can anybody suggest what's going on? It seems like anytime I need to use the `remote/branch` reference syntax is where it gets all messed up. I suspect that it's a problem that's arising from my use of --git-dir and --work-tree, but whenever I search for a solution, very few people have those same conditions.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, it had nothing to do with the --git-dir or --work-tree options.

I checked my origin and it was set up with an https://github.com/... address, so I replaced it by `git remote remove origin`, `git remote add origin git@github.com:...` form pointing at the same repo. After that, when I ran `git fetch`, there was a different prompt and it was clear that it actually fetched master, then the origin/master references worked.